# Quartus 2 VHDL Clock Frequency Divider: can't determine definition of operator "+"

Tags: vhdl, debugging

I'm extremely new to VHDL and trying to make some easy projects such that I learn the basics and syntax. I use Quartus 2 at home and ISE 10.1 at the school computer. I wrote exactly the same code in both of them where the code is:

```
        library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

    entity freq_divider is port(        

        clk: in std_logic;
        clkdividedby2,clkdividedby4,clkdividedby8: out std_logic
    );

    end freq_divider;

    architecture karakter of freq_divider is

    signal count4 : std_logic := '0'; --In this line, count4 is initialized as 0.
    signal count8 : std_logic_vector (1 downto 0) := "00"; -- Count 8 is initialized as 0.
    signal clkdividedby2_temp,clkdividedby4_temp,clkdividedby8_temp : std_logic :='0';

    begin

    process(clk) 



    begin
    if(rising_edge(clk)) then


    clkdividedby2_temp<= not clkdividedby2_temp;
    count4 <= count4 + '1';
    count8 <= count8 + "01";

    if(count4 = '1') then -- = Tests for equality, not ==
    clkdividedby4_temp<= not clkdividedby4_temp;
    count4<='0';
    end if;

    if(count8 = "11") then
    clkdividedby8_temp<= not clkdividedby8_temp;
    count8<="00";
    end if;

    end if;
    end process;

    clkdividedby2<=clkdividedby2_temp;
    clkdividedby4<=clkdividedby4_temp;
    clkdividedby8<=clkdividedby8_temp;

    end karakter;
```

This synthesized perfectly on ISE 10.1 in school, but in Quartus 2, I get the error:

> Can't determine definition of operator ""+"" -- found 0 possible definitions

I have no idea why this is happening. I wrote all the libraries and stuff, and it is still not working.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to perform addition on `std_logic` and `std_logic_vector` -- that makes no sense in VHDL, because these types do not hold numerical values.

If you want addition to work, you need to use either

- a type that has well-defined overflow semantics, so it is clear what should happen if two `'1'` values meet in an addition, *or*
- a type that is a pure numerical value and does not have a representation attached.

For a counter that is only compared against a fixed value, but never read, I'd go with the latter, change the type to `natural` and give it a `range` constraint, and leave it up to the compiler to select an internal representation.

Comment: But why it makes sense in ISE, but not Quartus ? I used my code in school in ISE 10.1 and it worked, in quartus 2 it did not.

Comment: My initial guess is that they are trying to be "helpful".

Comment: well, I defined count4 and count8 as integers and now the code is working perfectly, but the thing is, compiler uses two 32 bits numbers when a single bit and two bits are necessary for count4 and count8 respectively. Isnt it a waste of memory or will it reduce the number of bits used in the optimization ?

Comment: In VHDL, you can limit allowed values using the `range` keyword. If you limit to `0 to 3`, you would get the desired behaviour, but also an error in simulation because you assign the value `4` for a short time, even if you immediately overwrite it later (because `<=` assignments are not performed until the end of the block).

Answer (score 1):

Addition for type std_logic_vector is supported in the IEEE package numeric_std_unsigned as well as the Synopsys package std_logic_unsigned.

What isn't supported is addition for type std_logic, where addition would be equivalent to "and". Replace `count4 <= count4 + '1';` with `count4 <= not count4;` or just use clkdividedby2_temp.

You could likewise show the temp flipflops as part of same std_logic_vectors by making count4 length 2 and count8 length 3 and assigning the MSB's to clkdividedby4 and clkdividedby8 as well as renaming clkdividedby2_temp count2.

You could also use use a single 3 bit counter:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
-- use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
-- OR use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all;

entity freq_divider is
     port (        
        clk:            in  std_logic;
        clkdividedby2, 
        clkdividedby4, 
        clkdividedby8:  out std_logic
    );
end entity freq_divider;

architecture foo of freq_divider is
    signal count : std_logic_vector (2 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
    process (clk) 
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            count <= count + 1;
        end if;
    end process;

    clkdividedby2 <= count(0);
    clkdividedby4 <= count(1);
    clkdividedby8 <= count(2);

end architecture;
```

and with a small testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity freq_divider_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of freq_divider_tb is
    signal clk:             std_logic := '0';
    signal clkdividedby2:   std_logic;
    signal clkdividedby4:   std_logic;
    signal clkdividedby8:    std_logic;
begin
DUT:
    entity work.freq_divider
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            clkdividedby2 => clkdividedby2,
            clkdividedby4 => clkdividedby4,
            clkdividedby8 => clkdividedby8
        );
CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 5 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if now > 160 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

You would get:

[image: freq_divider_tb.png]

while saving some flip flops by modeling hardware.

Comment: There is very little difference between your code and mine. I tried to write count4<=count4+1 in my code but mine is still not working and giving the same error. I did not understand how count<= count + '1' means and operation but count<=count +1 does not ? I also tried your code with count<=count+"001" and it is working as well. Im confused

Comment: Oh I got you I guess. For single bits, we cant make the things work by count<=count + '1'; . I still dont get why it means and though ? But it is safe to say count4<=count4 +"01" if it was a std_logic_vector of size 2 right ?